# image sizes between differently sized iphones

Tags: ios, image, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game, with sprite-kit and swift. I understand you can use  @3x @2x @1x etc. however in testing this on an iphone 5s and 6 they both load the @2x.

Is there a way to handle this better? am I missing something?

Comment: I phone doesn't help much with handling screen sizes, especially if your game needs to be proportional to balance difficulty.  The 2x will load the same size image for a 5 and a 6 which doesn't make much sense to me either.  What I did was design my screen in arbitrary units at a 3:2 ratio.  This is my playable area.  For each device, I find the biggest playable area and convert my units to pixels.  I also designate a scale factor for my images.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhones 5s and 6 both use @2x. The only device to use @3x is the iPhone 6 Plus. [Apple's docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)